# how to decide to which appdomain the input is going when providing input to a process in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, process, appdomain

i have created a a process using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. herez the code

```
Process p = new Process()
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"some.exe")
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                ErrorDialog = false,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false
            }

            };
            p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, r) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(r.Data);
            };
            p.Start();

            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            int counter = 0;

            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);
            p.StandardInput.WriteLine("INPUT" + counter++);

            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

and in some.exe im creating 2 app domains which are infact console applications. using `AppDomain.ExecuteAsselbly("path to exe")`
so when i provide input to the process the 1st loaded appdomain is taking all the input and second one is not taking it.
is there any way of determining which appdomain should take the input?
EDIT:-
i suddenly realized that the term AppDomain is incorrectly used here. actually what i mean is that which thread in the current process should take the input.